# download a file

Tags: c#, winforms, download

I use these following codes to download a file from a specific url in C# windows application.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = @"DOWNLOADLINK";
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(web_DownloadFileCompleted);
    web.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"F:\a");
}

void web_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The file has been downloaded");
}
```

But it has an error for this line : `web.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"F:\a");`

It says :

> An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: Do you have permission to access the "F:\a" folder? Also, you need to specify a file, it should be something like "F:\a.txt"

Comment: You should also do a check with an if statement like this: if(File.Exists(filename)) { web.DownloadFile.... } else { MesagesBox.Show(...); }

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson Thanks. it worked. but it didn't tell me the file has been downloaded. What should I do if I want to download this file into this file's name not a.zip?

Comment: It didn't tell you? It could be your browser, Chrome does that to me sometimes. You could always add an alert to tell you the file has finished downloading.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson I want to show in messagebox. MessageBox.Show("The file has been downloaded");

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson Trolling? The `DownloadFileCompleted` event won't be fired when you call `DownloadFile`, only when you call `DownloadFileAsync`. `DownloadFile` blocks (i.e. code execution doesn't continue on the next line) until after the download has completed. Just put the `MessageBox.Show()` on the line after `web.DownloadFile()`.

Comment: @aliboy38 Read the answer I posted below, it's covered there!

Comment: @tomfanning ah, my bad. I haven't used the WebClient class before, that's why I am not trying to write an answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the event handler if you use `DownloadFile` rather than `DownloadFileAsync`.

Update: From chat it turned out that the OP wanted the filename on the filesystem to reflect the filename specified at the end of the URL. This is the solution:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.yourserver/path/to/yourfile.zip");
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    web.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), Path.Combine(@"f:\", filename));
}
```

Comment: It still has that error. It says : An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: Please post the WHOLE output from the message box.

Comment: it's ok if I use @"F:\a.zip. but I wanna use the filename.zip not a.zip

Comment: So just replace `@"f:\a.zip"` with `@"f:\filename.zip"`

Comment: so it will download the file in filename.zip for all of the files. but every file has different name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17268/discussion-between-tomfanning-and-aliboy38)